# Angular HttpClient does not send domain cookie

Tags: angular, cookies

I have an Angular app that runs on `angular.example.com`. The API runs on `app.example.com`. I get a domain cookie from `app.example.com` that sets the cookie on `.example.com` containing a JWT token (the cookie should be shareable between these domains according to RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3).

When the request to `angular.example.com` is sent and I can see the cookie as part of the request headers (added by the browser). The Angular app is served and makes a request to `app.example.com` to fetch some data.

I would expect that the cookie would be send along with this request by the browser, but it doesn't happen. Can anyone explain why this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XHR requests in Angular by default do not pass cookie information with each request. What this means is by default Angular doesn't pass Cookies captured on previous requests back to the server which effectively logs out the user.

And your server response must allow headers **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials**.

In order for that to work the HttpClient has to set the `withCredentials`:

> CORS - **Allow-Origin-With-Credentials**
>
> In addition to the client side **withCredentials** header, if you are going cross domain also make sure that the **Allow-Origin-With-Credentials** header is set on the server. If this header is not set the client side **withCredentials** also has no effect on cross-domain calls causing cookies and auth headers to not be sent.

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });
this.http.post(this.url, body , options);
```

Comment: just a note, when `Allow-Origin-With-Credentials` is set, the origin cannot be "*".

Answer (score 13):

HTTP does not resend cookies by default. You have to enable it, either per request with the config `{withCredentials: true}`, or create an `HttpInterceptor` to add it for all requests.

```
this.httpclient.get(myUrl, {withCredentials:true})
```

or: [Stackoverflow: Add credentials to every httpClient call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52834007/angular-6-set-withcredentials-to-true-with-every-httpclient-call)

Comment: I took me 2 hours to reach to this and I thought my code is broken